# Problems with tuple unpacking

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

In a function, i'm returning a list of two values if the values are there or an empty list, like below:

```
def func1(prikey):
    try:
      df = somesql
      for index, rW in df.iterrows():
          retvalue = [rW['id_in_int'],rW['time_in_str']]
    except:
        retvalue = []
    return retvalue
```

In the main code, i'm assigning to the variable:

```
newdf['newid'],newdf['thistime'] = func1(newdf['prikey'])
```

But i got the error "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)"
So, in the function, i tried as below

```
retvalue = [[],[]]
```

But got the error as "Length of values does not match length of index"
And `retvalue = [0,0]` didnt give any error and the value of `newdf['newid'],newdf['thistime']` is zero.

And, when i'm trying to check whether the value is zero in further lines as `if(newdf['newid']==0):`, which gives the error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

I tried checking `len()` as well which didnt work too.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Shailesh and samy for your responses. Inside the function, i used `retvalue = [0,0]` to resolve "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)" error.

The article https://towardsdatascience.com/apply-and-lambda-usage-in-pandas-b13a1ea037f7 helped me to use ".apply" on the series and below is the code.

```
newdf['newwaittime'] = newdf['newid'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x==0 else get_new_wait_time(x))
```

where I'm checking whether the value of `newdf['newid']` is zero or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't assign 0 to a column. try assigning ""(empty string) or `np.NaN`. Also `newdf['newid']` is of type `Series` and you can't compare it with a bool so you can use `newdf['newid'].empty` or `len(newdf['newid']) == 0`

Comment: tried retvalue = [np.NaN,np.NaN] and didnt receive the error.
But, while checking if(newdf['newid']==np.NaN):, getting the error as "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: I guess you have to use newdf['newid'].empty to check if it's empty, as it is a Series object and you can't compare it with a bool. you can also try if len(newdf['newid']) == 0

Answer (score 0):

Your code below returns 1 list,

```
def func1(prikey):
    try:
      df = somesql
      for index, rW in df.iterrows():
          retvalue = [rW['id_in_int'],rW['time_in_str']]  #here 1 list!
    except:
        retvalue = [] #here 1 list!
    return retvalue
```

This will result in the: "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)" error in your next statement:

```
newdf['newid'],newdf['thistime'] = func1(newdf['prikey'])
```

As there is no example code for the other error you described:

> The 'or' and 'and' python statements require truth-values. If these are
>   considered ambiguous you should use "bitwise" | (or) or & (and)
>   operations. [Check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: i indeed got through that link earlier, but im not using multiple conditions. Its just not working even for a single operator